# CSS text selection color overflows outside box

Tags: css

I'm new to CSS and was wondering if there was any way to stop the text selection color going into the 'gutter' (I think that's the term?) like here:

[image: screenshot of the issue]

I know it's something pretty trivial but I've noticed that none of the professional (online) websites that use a gap between columns have this problem.

If you float the column, it doesn't experience this issue.

So one solution seems to be floating both columns, but then I'm left with the issue of making a gap between the columns and the footer (I'd have to specify how much margin-top (no. of pixels from the header) I want for it, which isn't very dynamic).

Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is the current CSS code for it:

```
.box /*this is applied to all the divs*/
{
border: 1px black dotted;
padding:3px;
}

body
{
width: 850px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#panel0
{
background-color: blue;
}

#panel1
{
background-color:red;
width: 400px;
float:right;
}

#panel2
{
background-color:brown;
width:400px;
}

#panel3
{
background-color:yellow;
clear: right;
}
```

Comment: Try posting your HTML and css to jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ - it will enable people to quickly work with and tweak your CSS and HTML. My quick guess would be that you need to float any content within panel 2 as it's currently expanding outside of it's parent's boundaries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
#panel2
{
background-color:brown;
width:400px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: Glad it solved it. This is the solution I use 99% of the time. There are cases where it's not suitable though, for example if you have something that should expand outside of the container when clicked.