# Overflowing select highlight

Tags: css, selection, highlighting

What is the logic of the selection highlighting overflowing beyond the parent element?

In the attached screenshot, the top one is what I have currently, and the bottom one is a Photoshopped mockup of what I want to achieve.

To me it seems that the selection highlighting is almost largely random; I have not been able to find any definitive resources that explain what makes selection highlighting behave in which ways.

What should I keep in mind in terms of CSS and DOM when wanting to keep the selection highlighting reasonable?

[image: Select overflow example]

Comment: I don't believe you can influence this with CSS, or JavaScript. But I'd be interested to be proven wrong.

Comment: Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/dHaBJ/ Only work (can see different）in Chrome though. No safari for me to check.

Comment: Fiddle here; http://jsfiddle.net/TFvYu/ - I did notice `overflow: hidden` has some effect, but I have no idea how cross-browser it is, and if there are any other factors to consider.

Comment: @EmphramStavanger http://jsfiddle.net/TFvYu/2/ Adding `overflow:hidden` helps in Chrome (23). Firefox(17.0.1)'s selection will always be constrained; no IE & Safari here (Linux box). I wonder if this is WebKit's way of rendering.

Comment: Hmm... interesting. Can you think of any unintended side-effects to adding `overflow: hidden` to all `p` elements in the page?

Comment: Also, do plop your solution into an answer so I can mark this question answered. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Interestingly, I've wondered why SO doesn't have something like this so it's easier to copy code off an question/answer.</s>

Actually, SO does have contained highlighting in the `<code>` blocks relying on `overflow: auto;`. `<blockquotes>` do not have contained highlighting.

Anyway, it appears there are a few ways to solve this problem (though, I'm sure there might be more).  Use one of the following CSS rules to limit the highlighting of text to a specific element.

- `overflow: hidden;` or `overflow:auto;`
- `position: relative;`
- `float:left;` or `float:right;`

The working example below shows all four methods at work. Some are easier to work with depending on your needs.

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/TFvYu/4/

**Sources**

- [CSS text selection color overflows outside box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463244/css-text-selection-color-overflows-outside-box)
- [HTML/CSS How to prevent highlighting text from spanning entire width of page in google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239129/html-css-how-to-prevent-highlighting-text-from-spanning-entire-width-of-page-in)